# Blender 2.8 Evee problem with irradiance volume and reflection cube

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am very new in Blender, in fact, um using blender for 4 days only, I used to work with MAX mostly, Only reason to do some experiments with blender because of the new (2.8) update.

I am facing a weird problem, whenever I use blender mesh, like box, sphere & then try to use reflection probe and irradiance volume for evee rendering, it works fine, but whenever I import a scene from 3ds max the reflection probe just start to blow the whole scene, take a look at the attached file, is there something that I am doing wrong or it just a glitch? I believe I am doing something wrong here

By the way if you want to study the scene i can share it with you

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for stating your question clearly.
When you import .FBX files from MAX: Go to the object property tabs (to your right side of the screen) and locate the 3 vertex triangle icon. There you will see "normals tab". Uncheck "Custom normals".
Also, the MATERIAL which you´re importing from MAX is overriding the properties of a principled BSDF shader like Blender natively interprets. That is your "diffuse" material has probably a high value of white in its parameters (past 1). Solution: Go to your materials tab of your imported. .fbx object and delete the diffuse material (or any other weird network of materials in which these .fbx use to arrive at blender from max) and then SHIFT+A on the node editr, search for principled shader. Plug it into the Material output of your imported object. Voilá.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller